# Using mongodb indexes with hint()

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I came across this question in a mongodb course i was taking:
We have to find the paramaters to be passed to the below query's hint() to get the desired output.

```
var exp = db.restaurants.explain("executionStats")
exp.find({ "address.state": "NY", stars: { $gt: 3, $lt: 4 } }).sort({ name: 1 }).hint(REDACTED)
```

O/P:

```
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "m201.restaurants",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": "REDACTED",
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "SORT",
      "sortPattern": {
        "name": 1
      },
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "FETCH",
          "inputStage": {
            "stage": "IXSCAN",
            "keyPattern": "REDACTED",
            "indexName": "REDACTED",
            "isMultiKey": false,
            "isUnique": false,
            "isSparse": false,
            "isPartial": false,
            "indexVersion": 1,
            "direction": "forward",
            "indexBounds": "REDACTED"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": [ ]
  },
  "executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 3335,
    "executionTimeMillis": 20,
    "totalKeysExamined": 3335,
    "totalDocsExamined": 3335,
    "executionStages": "REDACTED"
  },
  "serverInfo": "REDACTED",
  "ok": 1
}
```

ANSWER THATS TO BE PUT IN :  { "address.state": 1, "stars": 1, "name": 1 }

Given the answer above what i dont understanding is, if **address.state, stars and name** are given as indexes, and since the query contains the **entire prefix in order of the compound index**, **the in memory sort stage shouldnt take place**. But here sorting happens inspite of having a **name index** in the end of the index parameters being passed to the function.
Why does a sort happen explicitly insipite of name index being specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, found the answer, the keys in the index can be used for filtering and sorting given, if the query predicate contains equality conditions only.
Since we use $gt and $lt, an explicit sort is performed here.

Order of the query for possible best performance: **Equality, sort, range**